# navigationItem.TitleView not working on iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios10, uinavigationitem

I have a problem with a titleview in navigationBar. The thing is that its not displayed when i assign a view into titleView. I've tried to use `navigationItem.title = @"eqweqweq";` but nothing happens.

This view involved is created by code, i dont know if that's the problem, because the other ViewControllers where i've used that worked perfectly.

Is there any bug in iOS 10 that i cant use titleView? Sometimes it works sometimes not.

I've search on google but nothing helped me. I hope somebody can help me T_T.

thank you

Comment: If you set a titleView then the title will not be used. Could you please show some code of what you are doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've solved the problem!

The problem was this function:

```
extension UINavigationController{
func applyWhiteEffect(){
        var bounds = self.navigationBar.bounds
        let whiteView = UIView()
        bounds.origin.y = -20
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.height + 20
        whiteView.frame = bounds
        whiteView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        whiteView.userInteractionEnabled = false
        whiteView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        whiteView.tag = 1000
        self.navigationBar.addSubview(whiteView)
        self.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.navigationBar.sendSubviewToBack(whiteView)
    }
}
```

This function applied a white view and there was a problem with that and iOS 10, so i've changed to this:

```
func applyWhiteEffect(){
        var bounds = self.navigationBar.bounds
        let whiteView = UIView()
        bounds.origin.y = -20
        bounds.size.height = 20
        whiteView.frame = bounds
        whiteView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        whiteView.userInteractionEnabled = false
        whiteView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        whiteView.tag = 1000
        self.navigationBar.addSubview(whiteView)
        self.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.navigationBar.sendSubviewToBack(whiteView)
    }
```

Changing the view to only cover status bar and `self.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()`

Thanks guys for helping me anyway :D

Answer (score 5):

Just use one at a time.

Either set `titleView` of `navigationItem` like below:

```
UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
lblTitle.text = @"eqweqweq";
lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[lblTitle sizeToFit];

self.navigationItem.titleView = lblTitle;
```

**OR**

Directly set `title` of `navigationItem` like below:

```
navigationItem.title=@"eqweqweq"
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you **set size** of your custom titleView. For example use **titleLabel.sizeToFit()** before setting titleView.

```
let titleLabel = UILabel()
titleLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: attributes)
titleLabel.sizeToFit()  // Important part
navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the titleView in the viewWillApear function.

Answer (score -3):

Please try this. It works for me.

```
self.title = "eqweqweq"
```

Hope it will helps you.Thanks

Comment: questioner wanted to implement a view at titleView